# Why Select * Only return the first record in a group?

Tags: sql, select, having

I am studying the `Group by` and `Having` clauses in a SQL statement. In the following page, what I want are all customers whose country contain more than 5 customers in the database.

So I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
GROUP BY Country 
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5
```

in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_having

But this select only returns the first record in the group, not all records in the group. Why?

Comment: Why are you using * with group by? There is no meaning of grouping with *

Comment: @alancc . . . Your code would generate an error in almost all databases, include the most recent versions of MySQL.  Use `GROUP BY` when you have aggregation functions.  It is never used with `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But select only returns the first record in the group, not all records in the group. Why?

Because one row per group is what `GROUP BY` *does*.

The way to do what you want to do is to figure out which countries have more that 5 customers, then return all records from those countries:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN
(SELECT Country FROM Customers GROUP BY Country HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5)
```

Comment: Sorry but I search "Group by sql" on Google and find top links, such as https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/ , both do not mention that only one row will be returned for each group.

Comment: @alancc W3Schools is **not** a great resource for SQL, you would be better off finding a resource more directly related to your database engine (mySQL, SQL Server etc)

Comment: @JonP is correct — those tutorials leave out so much they're almost worthless. For example, [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) say "`GROUP BY` will condense into a single row all selected rows that share the same values for the grouped expressions." You are supposed to use aggregate functions (such as `COUNT` or `MAX`) to select what information from each group you want to appear in that single row.

Comment: @Amadan, I check the SQL Server document on Group By at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, it said "The SELECT statement returns one row per group.", but does not say which row it will return if using "Select *"?

Comment: It does say "each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the <select> list must be included in the GROUP BY list" though. And as `*` is equivalent to listing all fields, `SELECT * Customers GROUP BY Country` is invalid unless `Country` is the only field, as all other fields will not be "included in the GROUP BY list". I am not experienced with MSSQL, but I would expect that query to raise an error. And if it does not, it is arbitrary which values are selected out of the grouped rows. As @Atk said, there's no meaning of grouping with `*`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I make a test and confirm you are correct. It seems that w3schools using a different SQL system that will allow select nonaggregate expression.